# Workflow 2013 - Update list item to not replace existing text but add to it

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, 2019

I am using SharePoint 2019OP with a 2013 Workflow.

I have a workflow that add's a line of text to a comments box, via Update List Item action.

If there is existing text in the comment box, the existing text is deleted.

Is there a way to add to existing text via the workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to append the field value, just add the current field value in string builder, then fill in the required new content into the text field.
[image]